# How to efficiently debug webpack applications?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, webpack

I am trying to adopt webpack dev server in my project. I know it's quite widely adopted, so it surprised me that debugging the application seems to be quite hard. Since webpack by default produces a single giant bundle, source maps are a must. I have a big problem with them:

Depending on `devtool` mode, source maps are either slow to parse (`eval`) or not used to map some stack traces (`eval-source-map`), e.g  there are times the entire stack trace looks like this:
`at eval (eval at <anonymous>  http://localhost:8082/js/app.js:2004:2), <anonymous>:43:67)`.
Also, when you manually call console.trace or console.error the output is not mapped. So you have to use tools like [sourcemapped-stacktrace](https://github.com/novocaine/sourcemapped-stacktrace) - this is both slow, and error-prone.

Currently I use require.js for development because it allows me to debug the application very easily - each and every stack trace points to the correct file and line.

How do I achieve the same result with webpack?

EDIT:
Related issue in google chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376409

Related issue in firefox:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=583083

Answer (score 2):

Which devtools do you use? Millage may vary, but Chrome (and IE/Edge, yes...IE and Edge) tend to handle sourcemaps the best. While at this point all the major browsers support them, I've had the worse experience with Firefox.

We have very very large bundles and sourcemaps have not caused any slowness in devtools. Which mode are you using? For webpack, using "eval" will do an inline sourcemap that maps files, but not source (so you see the generated code, but 1:1 correlation with the original files). Since a lot of ES6, Typescript and Coffeescript constructs don't map well (eg: generators or comprehensions), this is usually the easiest mode to use, and is also the fastest. Using eval alsoensure it "just works" in Chrome devtools without any action from the developer (your files will be under the webpack:// pseudo-folder)

For the stack trace, I don't know if it is browser specific or what. We use Mocha for unit test, which doesn't look like it's doing anything special for sourcemaps, and it captures stack traces to render them on the test runner's webpack properly (it even includes the webpack:// prefix along with the original file name and proper line number), so maybe the need for that library is browser specific or outdated?

Comment: Well sometime it works sometime it doesn't, e.g. there are times entire stack trace looks like this: `at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8082/js/app.js:2004:2), <anonymous>:43:67)`

Comment: Another example is when you manually call `console.trace` or `console.error` the output is not mapped, and some promise libraries are doing that. Also there are some interesting results in conjunction with async traces in chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

I have found it useful to add an `npm run watch` task that kicks off webpack like so:

`webpack -w --devtool eval`

This results in source maps that at least have the correct module name. It is somewhat confusing though as the source mapped source is pre-some sort of processing (babel)? So you'll see in the source something like:

`import react from 'react';`

But the actual variable name will be munged to something like `_react2` or similar. I'd love for the mapped source to be the processed version with the ugly variable names or for the scope to have the definitions as seen in the mapped source.

The actual line I have in my `package.json` for the above task is:

```
  "scripts": {
    // other lines edited out
    "watch": "node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -w --devtool eval"
  }
```

Comment: babel has a `--preserve-lines` option so it's possible to live with those mangled variable names; the real problem are stack traces - I updated my question with some more details

Comment: @AdamZieliński ah! thanks for the tip, I should have looked closer but I'll put that into practice right away. I unfortunately don't have anything to help w/ the stack traces.