# Getting a stack trace I can use when using webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, webpack, devtools

This is a general question.
Sometimes I get an error when developing with angular and webpack that the entire stack trace is lines from bundle.js or angular.js (sometimes jquery.js).
Is it possible to see where the error actually came from (I mean in my code)?

I've looked into devtool types in https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html
but even when I use eval-source-map I can't get anything I can use (using `devtool:source-map` is out of the question because it's insanely slow).

Thanks.

Comment: Insanely slow? On a 2-year-old Macbook Pro I barely notice the compile time with `devtool: 'source-map'` and I certainly don't feel the difference with it on or off (compiled code is about 700KB for me). Are you doing a complete build every time or are you using webpack-dev-server?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766985/how-to-efficiently-debug-webpack-applications